# Code Analysis Validation of Views in DACPAC using DacFX

Tags: c#, database-project, dacpac

I am trying to create custom code analysis for database projects. I have a couple of validations written for tables that are currently working fine. However, my first validation for views does not seem to work. When debugging the rules, it will actually break into the rule once and only once. At that time the ruleExecutionContext.ModelElement is null. I have looked around for another class to use besides the view type class, but that seems to be the correct one to use. I am currently using this version of SSDT: SSDT_14.0.61021.0_EN along with Visual Studio 2015. I am at a complete loss as to why the table tests work, but the views do not.

```
[ExportCodeAnalysisRule(NestedViewRule.RuleId,
    NestedViewRule.RuleDisplayName,
    Description = NestedViewRule.RuleDisplayName,
    Category = Constants.Performance,
    RuleScope = SqlRuleScope.Model)]
public sealed class NestedViewRule : SqlCodeAnalysisRule
{
    public const string RuleId = Constants.RuleNameSpace + "SRP0001";
    public const string RuleDisplayName = "Views should not use other views as a data source";
    public const string Message = "View {0} uses view {1} as a datasource. This has a negative impact upon performance.";

    public NestedViewRule()
    {
        SupportedElementTypes = new[] { ModelSchema.View }; // View.TypeClass, neither seems to work
    }

    public override IList<SqlRuleProblem> Analyze(SqlRuleExecutionContext ruleExecutionContext)
    {
        List<SqlRuleProblem> problems = new List<SqlRuleProblem>();
        TSqlObject sqlObj = ruleExecutionContext.ModelElement;
        if (sqlObj != null)
        {
            foreach (var child in sqlObj.GetReferenced(DacQueryScopes.All).Where(x => x.ObjectType == View.TypeClass))
            {
                string msg = string.Format(Message, RuleUtils.GetElementName(ruleExecutionContext, sqlObj), RuleUtils.GetElementName(ruleExecutionContext, child));
                problems.Add(new SqlRuleProblem(msg, sqlObj) /*{ Severity = SqlRuleProblemSeverity.Error } */);
            }
        }

        return problems;
    }
}
```

Here is one of my currently working table rules in case anyone is interested:

```
[ExportCodeAnalysisRule(TableHasPrimaryKeyRule.RuleId,
    TableHasPrimaryKeyRule.RuleDisplayName,
    Description = TableHasPrimaryKeyRule.RuleDisplayName,
    Category = Constants.BestPractice,
    RuleScope = SqlRuleScope.Element)]
public sealed class TableHasPrimaryKeyRule : SqlCodeAnalysisRule
{
    public const string RuleId = Constants.RuleNameSpace + "SRB0002";
    public const string RuleDisplayName = "Tables should have a primary key.";
    public const string Message = "Table {0} does not have a primary key.";

    public TableHasPrimaryKeyRule()
    {
        SupportedElementTypes = new[] { ModelSchema.Table };
    }

    public override IList<SqlRuleProblem> Analyze(SqlRuleExecutionContext ruleExecutionContext)
    {
        List<SqlRuleProblem> problems = new List<SqlRuleProblem>();
        TSqlObject sqlObj = ruleExecutionContext.ModelElement;
        if (sqlObj != null)
        {
            var child = sqlObj.GetChildren(DacQueryScopes.All).FirstOrDefault(x => x.ObjectType == PrimaryKeyConstraint.TypeClass);
            if (child == null)
            {
                string msg = string.Format(Message, RuleUtils.GetElementName(ruleExecutionContext, sqlObj));
                problems.Add(new SqlRuleProblem(msg, sqlObj));
            }
        }

        return problems;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I apologize, but after I posted it I noticed that I was using RuleScope = SqlRuleScope.Model for the view check, and Element for the Tables. I then deduced that was forcing the visitor pattern for the view registration to be ignored, and the model to be passed to me the one time.

Changing the attribute to match the table checks using RuleScope = SqlRuleScope.Element fixed the issue.

Comment: Yep, model scope is really just for when you need to do a single pass (for example if your design scans all objects & flags on correlated issues. You can query the model for element types (e.g. model.GetObjects() call) but the best thing to do is use element scope if you want element-by-element analysis